# Are redundancy and reflection my only options here?

Tags: c#

I have a function - `TriggerNotifications` - that accepts a `NotificationType`.  The Type determines which settings I should pull from the `User`.

The code looks like this:

```
public void TriggerNotification(DbContext db, User user, NotificationType type, string content) {
            switch (type) {
                case NotificationType.Followed:
                    CreateNotification(db, user, user.Followed, content);
                    return;
                case NotificationType.Unfollowed:
                    CreateNotification(db, user, user.Unfollowed, content);
                    return;
                case NotificationType.Messaged:
                    CreateNotification(db, user, user.Messaged, content);
                    return;
                default: 
                    throw new InvalidDataContractException("Invalid Notification Type");
            }
        }
```

So the only purpose of this method is to determine which settings should be used.  Every `User` has a property matching each of the enum `NotificationTypes`.

I think this is a good use case for reflection, but want to ask if there's any other way to reduce redundancy here.  I don't like reflection because it's not as straightforward to debug, and it's slow (right?).

**UPDATE**

**CreateNotification:**

```
private void CreateNotification(DbContext db, User user, NotificationSetting setting, string content) {
        // send email, notification, or both
        if (setting.Equals(NotificationSetting.None))
            return;
        var notification = new Notification() {
            UserId = user.userId
            Description = content,
            Email = email,
        };

        if (setting.Equals(NotificationSetting.Email) || setting.Equals(NotificationSetting.Both)) {
            // tell worker role to pick it up
            notification.PendingEmail = true;
        }

        // signalR stuff here

        db.Add(notification);
    }
```

**User:**

```
public class User : Settings {
      // other stuff
}
```

**Settings:**

```
public abstract class Settings {
    // notifications
    public NotificationSetting Followed { get; set; }
    public NotificationSetting Unfollowed { get; set; }
    public NotificationSetting Messaged { get; set; }
}
```

**NotificationSetting:**

```
// values stored in the db for each setting property - messaged, unfollowed, etc
public enum NotificationSetting {
    Navbar,
    Email,
    Both,
    None
}
```

**NotificationType:**

```
// values used in logic only to tell the notification builder which setting to pull
public enum NotificationType {
    Followed,
    Unfollowed,
    Messaged
}
```

Comment: It's good to be aware what is slow, but unless you actually have a good reason to worry about the performance of this code, don't base your decisions on it.

Comment: Though using reflection *is* a code smell and you are right to ask about ways of avoiding it.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the redundancy is accidental, and some essential to your design (not essential to problem though, if it were essential to problem reflection wouldn't help).

Accidental redundancy can be removed thus:

```
private static NotificationSetting GetNotificationSetting(User user, NotificationType type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case NotificationType.Followed: return user.Followed;
    case NotificationType.Unfollowed: return user.Unfollowed;
    case NotificationType.Messaged: return user.Messaged;
    default: 
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Invalid Notification Type");
    }
}

public void TriggerNotification(object db, User user, NotificationType type, string content) {
    CreateNotification(db, user, GetNotificationSetting(user,type), content);
}
```

Note:

- I changed the exception as `InvalidDataContractException` seems to be serialization related.
- `GetNotificationSetting` should be moved to `User` (or made an extension method of that class).

Now that this is out of the way,

### What can you change in the design to remove redundancy?

Your user entity is not normalized. If you really were doing code-first design, `User` would look like this instead:

```
class User: Settings
{
}

public abstract class Settings {
    public IDictionary<NotificationType, NotificationSetting> NotificationSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Then `TriggerNotification` becomes just:

```
public void TriggerNotification(object db, User user, NotificationType type, string content) {
    CreateNotification(db, user, user.NotificationSettings[type], content);
}
```

Another redundancy is in `NotificationSetting`. It clearly is a bitmask.

```
[Flags]
public enum NotificationSetting : uint
{
  Navbar = 1,
  Email = 2,
// can add more like so
  Telegram = 4,
  PersonalVisit = 8,
}
```

Then

```
if (setting.Equals(NotificationSetting.Email) || setting.Equals(NotificationSetting.Both))
```

becomes

```
if (setting.HasFlag(NotificationSetting.Email))
```

Comment: `class User {}` Did you mean to make `User` inherit from `Settings`, just like in the original design? Though I'm not sure that's actually a good idea.

Comment: @svick Yes. Fixed it.

Comment: @svick There are other points as you point out. `User` is not a `Settings`, `User` has a `Settings`. `CreateNotification` should be just a factory method. Number of `NotificationX` suggest some sort of event setup.

Answer (score 2):

The redundancy is hard to remove and constructions like these make it hard to extend the options later. It would require updates to both data contracts and all classes implementing them.

You could use a delegate instead of a switch/case to improve extensibility, it would not completely remove the redundancy:

```
var actions = Dictionary<NotificationType, Func<DbContext, User, content>>()
{
    { 
        NotificationType.Followed, (context, user, content) => CreateNotification(context, user.Followed, content),
        NotificationType.Messaged, (context, user, content) => CreateNotification(context, user.Messaged, content),
        NotificationType.Unfollowed, (context, user, content) => CreateNotification(context, user.Unfollowed, content)
     };
 }
```

That way you can invoke it like this:

```
 Action<DbContext, User, content>> action = null;
 if (actions.TryGetValue(notification, out action)
 {
     action.Invoke(context, user, content);
 }
 else
 {
    // throw exception?
 }
```

You can also change your baseclass to be more extensible:

```
 public abstract class Settings
 {

     void SetNotificationAction(NotificationType nt, Func action)
     {
         // you could also replace the action if you so desire
         actions.Add(nt, action);
     }

     void ClearNotificationAction(NotificationType nt)
     {
         // you could also replace the action if you so desire
         actions.Remove(nt);
     }

     virtual void SetDefaultActions()
     {
         SetNotificationAction(NotificationSetting.Followed, () => return );
         ...
         ...
     }
 }
```

That does away with the enum passing and you can fetch the action using the method above. Each class inheriting can override the `SetDefaultActions` or manipulate the actions in the actions dictionary.

Comment: Why not just pull the value from the `Dictionary`? If it's an invalid value, you'll have your exception for free! :)

Comment: Because then you get some stupid, unintelligible exception message. This way you can actually throw somethign useful.

Comment: The `KeyNotFoundException` would (should?) never be thrown in production code, so a custom exception makes no sense to me. "The given key was not present in the dictionary" says exactly what's going on, and the stack trace will point to `Dictionary.GetValue` in the very method you're doing that, which is all you need to debug the issue. I don't see the added value of a custom exception message in this case, it's overkill.

Comment: enum's are trivially serializable, delegates not. How would you store notification setting for each user in db?

Comment: The enums are still stored in the DB. The delegates are replacing te handling code, not the actual values.

Comment: If so, `SetNotificationAction` being an instance method (non static) doesn't make sense. In fact `actions` should also be static and noone should be changing it.

Comment: Why not? Other classes that inherit might want to configure a different handlign method, it still doesn't change the actual Enum values. But how theyre handled can change from class to class.